# WKWebView allow 3rd-party cookies

Tags: swift, xcode, cookies, wkwebview

I have an app which uses a WKWebView. I also can access my dropbox account. But when I try to login I get the message from dropbox "You need to allow third-party cookies" and I cannot login. I also integrated harvest App and also cannot login there.

But when I click sign in on harvest app login the WebView loads and shows my logged in data, but back again on my website it still shows the login screen.

When I check which cookies are set in my webView there are actual set cookies from getharvest.com, platform.harvestapp.com and harvestapp.com. So do not know why there is any problem related to the cookies.

```
webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies({ (cookies: [HTTPCookie]) in
     print(cookies)
})
```

On the dropbox site I do not came to a login screen since dropbox is catching the check for third party cookies and do not let me access the login form.

Just the cookie for example:

```
<NSHTTPCookie
    version:1
    name:_harvest_sess
    value:GjT6ZtYXL...my ID ...YqbTwg%3D%3D
    expiresDate:'2021-04-04 21:24:43 +0000'
    created:'2021-03-20 21:24:43 +0000'
    sessionOnly:FALSE
    domain:.harvestapp.com
    partition:none
    sameSite:none
    path:/
    isSecure:TRUE
    isHTTPOnly: YES
 path:"/" isSecure:TRUE isHTTPOnly: YES>
```